# using javascript develop flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I just wonder if there is solution for me to develop flash using javascript.
I am familiar with javascript. Do not hope to learn a new language.

Welcome any comment

Comment: Actionscript is pretty much like JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this JavaScript API, but I don't think you'll be able to find a way to do everything in JS instead of AS.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fe8.html

Answer (score 0):

U may try to use jquery (or any other javascript library) to do this..

something like this (demo) : http://robot.anthonycalzadilla.com/
u can start here: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-robot/

Comment: To be clear, this is _not_ flash.

Comment: @AlexWayne i know bro :) .. but i think he mean making "flash-like" animations using javascript.